# how to populate an empty json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an empty json object like this

```
var image, description ;

var json = { 0 : { image : " " , description : " " } };
```

I want to populate like this by looping through n but this way of adding properties it gives be this error : "cannot set property description of undefined"

```
json[n].description = " nth description";
json[n].image =   " nth image";
```

In the end I want var json to be like this

```
var json = { 0 : {"image" : "1st image", "description" : "2nd description"  }
             1 : {"image" : "2nd image", "description" : "2nd description" }
             2 : {"image" : "3rd image ", "description" : "3rd description" }
             3 : {"image" : "4th image ", "description" : "4th description" }
}
```

and so on ....
 I get the undefined error on the first iteration so I haven't even attempted adding the second or third elements yet so not sure if that would need something else.

Comment: In the console it is working fine for me...
May be you are iterating even when other element hasn't been created ... Instead you should make a child object and push it to an array instead of this json type object. Something like this :
var json = [ {image : , description : }]

Answer (score 4):

Because in your example, if `n` is anything else than `0`, the object is undefined.

Create the empty object before using it :

```
json[n] = {};
json[n].description = " nth description";
json[n].image = " nth image";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
var json =  {}
json[n] = {}
json[n].description = " ....."
json[n].image = " ..... "
```

You need to create the new object inside the original and then declare its properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can code like this.

```
var nt = ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'];
var json = {};
for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        var tp = json[i]  = {}; //define first if it a object otherwise it say undefined.
        tp['image'] = i+nt[(i%10)]+' image';

        tp['image'] = i+nt[(i%10)]+' description';
    }
    console.log(json);
```

Comment: 1st, 2nd like that you want again you have to use some arrays for that